# So how do I run code from another file when requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, discord, discord.js

The code is for a discord bot, what I want to do is when the message '!setup' is sent into the discord chat it sends the code from '2ndQ.js' (The second section of code)

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === ping_char+'setup') {
    msg.channel.send(install 2ndQ);
  }
```

What it should run is this, after '!setup' is entered into the discord message it should print menu and then the user enters '1, 2 or 3' depending on what they want to do!

Printing isn't an issue the issue is how I can get this code to run when imported from another file.

I am using repl.it to code the bot of which I am using node.js

```
var menu = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Options: ")
  .setDescription("Here are the different options for this bot!")
  .addField("--> 1 = Casino", "Change prices of items and payout amount!")
  .addField("--> 2 = Quotes", "Change around the quotes eg add a quote to the quote list")
  .addField("--> 3 = Moderation", "Kick, Ban members and much more")
  .addField("--> More to come in the future", "Leave some suggestions!")
  .setImage("https://www.bolero.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/inr-banner-sercure.jpg")

var casino = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("--> Casino:")
  .setDescription("Here are the different options under the Casino section!")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **slot machine**", "Type [SLR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **blackjack**", "Type [BJR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **cock fight**", "Type [CFR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change price of **chicken** for **cock fight**", "Type [CFP = Price]")
  .addField("----> Change price of **lottery tickets**", "Type [LTP = x1(number), x5(number), x10(number), x100(number)]")
  .setImage("https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f")

var casino = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("--> Casino:")
  .setDescription("Here are the different options under the Casino section!")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **slot machine**", "Type [SLR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **blackjack**", "Type [BJR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change payout range on **cock fight**", "Type [CFR = Min(number), Max(number)]")
  .addField("----> Change price of **chicken** for **cock fight**", "Type [CFP = Price]")
  .addField("----> Change price of **lottery tickets**", "Type [LTP = x1(number), x5(number), x10(number), x100(number)]")
  .setImage("https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f")

var quote = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("--> Quotes:")
  .setDescription("Here are the different options under the Casino section!")
  .addField("----> Clear **quotes**", "Type [Clear quotes]")
  .addField("----> Add to quotes", "Type [Add (quote....- first name, last name)]")
  .addField("----> Remove a quote", "Type [Remove (quote...)]")
  .setImage("https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f")

var mod = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("--> Casino:")
  .setDescription("Here are the different options under the Casino section!")
  .addField("----> **Ban** a member", "Type [Ban @member]")
  .addField("----> **Warn** a member", "Type [Warn @member]")
  .addField("----> Create a **self role* message", "Type [Create ]")
  .setImage("https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f")




client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (ch) => ch.name === "general"
  );
  if (!channel) return;
  channel.send(
    "Welcome to the server, I'm the resident bot."
  );
});

channel.send(menu)
ping_char = '!'
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === ping_char+'1') {
    msg.channel.send(casino);
  }
  if (msg.content === ping_char+'2') {
    msg.channel.send(quote);
  }
    if (msg.content === ping_char+'3') {
    msg.channel.send(mod);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could export an object with a function/method from `2ndQ.js` and `require` it in your main file like this:

```
const command = require('./2ndQ.js')
```

Now, you can call the method (let's call it `execute()`) from your exported object and as you will need access the `message` in there, pass it as an argument.

```js
// index.js
// ...
const ping_char = '!';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === `${ping_char}setup`) {
    const command = require('./2ndQ.js');
    command.execute(message);
  }
});
```

In `2ndQ.js`, you will need to import `Discord` again, so you can use embeds.

However, checking the message content is not the right way to check if a user is responded after the `!setup` command. Although you said *printing isn't an issue*; using your code at the moment anyone could send a number without even calling the `setup` command and the bot would send the embed.

Discord has collectors, and you can set up one using the [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) method. It basically listens to incoming messages and checks if the user who sent the message is the one who sent the current one.

When the `collect` event fires, you can check the response content and send the corresponding embed. Check out the working code below:

```js
// 2ndQ.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const menu = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Options: ')
  .setDescription('Here are the different options for this bot!')
  .addField('--> 1 = Casino', 'Change prices of items and payout amount!')
  .addField(
    '--> 2 = Quotes',
    'Change around the quotes eg add a quote to the quote list',
  )
  .addField('--> 3 = Moderation', 'Kick, Ban members and much more')
  .addField('--> More to come in the future', 'Leave come suggetions!')
  .setImage(
    'https://www.bolero.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/inr-banner-sercure.jpg',
  );

const casino = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('--> Casino:')
  .setDescription('Here are the different options under the Casino section!')
  .addField(
    '----> Change payout range on **slot machine**',
    'Type [SLR = Min(number), Max(number)]',
  )
  .addField(
    '----> Change payout range on **blackjack**',
    'Type [BJR = Min(number), Max(number)]',
  )
  .addField(
    '----> Change payout range on **cock fight**',
    'Type [CFR = Min(number), Max(number)]',
  )
  .addField(
    '----> Change price of **chicken** for **cock fight**',
    'Type [CFP = Price]',
  )
  .addField(
    '----> Change price of **lottery tickets**',
    'Type [LTP = x1(number), x5(number), x10(number), x100(number)]',
  )
  .setImage(
    'https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f',
  );

const quote = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('--> Quotes:')
  .setDescription('Here are the different options under the Casino section!')
  .addField('----> Clear **quotes**', 'Type [Clear quotes]')
  .addField(
    '----> Add to quotes',
    'Type [Add (quote....- first name, last name)]',
  )
  .addField('----> Remove a quote', 'Type [Remove (quote...)]')
  .setImage(
    'https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f',
  );

const mod = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('--> Moderation:')
  .setDescription('Here are the different options under the Casino section!')
  .addField('----> **Ban** a member', 'Type [Ban @member]')
  .addField('----> **Warn** a member', 'Type [Warn @member]')
  .addField('----> Create a **self role* message', 'Type [Create ]')
  .setImage(
    'https://www.startus.cc/sites/default/files/styles/company_profile_cover_crop/public/img-casino.jpg?itok=E1XXjp5b&sc=775a4769d2582602853a3c7b3efeed6f',
  );

module.exports = {
  async execute(message) {
    // just send that menu
    await message.channel.send(menu);

    // filter checks if the response is from the author who typed the command
    const filter = (response) => response.author.id === message.author.id;
    const maxWait = 10000; // in ms

    // set up a message collector to check if there are any responses
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      // set up the max wait time the collector runs
      // it's optional though
      time: maxWait,
    });
    // fires when a response is collected
    collector.on('collect', (response) => {
      if (response.content === '1') {
        return message.channel.send(casino);
      }
      if (response.content === '2') {
        return message.channel.send(quote);
      }
      if (response.content === '3') {
        return message.channel.send(mod);
      }
    });

    // fires when the collector is finished collecting
    collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
      // only send a message when the "end" event fires because of timeout
      if (reason !== 'time') return;

      message.channel.send(
        `Okay, ${message.author}, I'm bored and I can't wait any longer. If you want to see the menu again, type \`!setup\` again`,
      );
    });
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Ok so doing this means I get this error:

`/home/runner/Java-discord-bot/index.js:320
    command.execute(msg);
            ^

TypeError: command.execute is not a function`

@marc_s @Zslot

Comment: I can't really help without seeing your code. Can you paste it on a site like pastebin.com?

Comment: im coding it in repl.it which has an invite system, ill give you the link to that if you want!

Comment: Here is the link:
https://replit.com/join/tqkwjolj-16cookj

@Zsolt Meszaros